# Jquery .val() == ** adding multiple possible answers **

Tags: javascript, jquery

I achived this by doing the following, but as a newbie to javascript and jquery i want to know if there is any shorter way to add multiple possible values.

```
if ($("input:first").val().toUpperCase() == "UNITED STATES" || $("input:first").val().toUpperCase() == "USA" || $("input:first").val().toUpperCase() == "AMERICA") {
                $("#check").text("Correct!").show().fadeOut(5000);
                return true;
```

Like

```
if ($("input:first").val().toUpperCase() == ("UNITED STATES","USA","AMERICA")) {
                $("#check").text("Correct!").show().fadeOut(5000);
                return true;
```

by this only validates the last answers in this case AMERICA.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):

```
if( $.inArray( $("input:first").val().toUpperCase(), [ "UNITED STATES", "USA", "AMERICA" ] ) > -1 ) { ...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4ar2G/

Comment: `$.inArray()` is just a shim for `Array.prototype.indexOf`.

Comment: @Alnitak I thought this was jQuery filling a gap. Good info!

Comment: @iambriansreed well, it is kinda, it's filling a gap for old crappy browsers that don't have `Array.prototype.indexOf`... ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak I just saw that. Damn IE7.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an object where the keys are the required values and the `in` operator:

```
var matches = { 'UNITED STATES': 1, 'USA': 1, 'AMERICA': 1 };

if ($("input:first").val().toUpperCase() in matches) {
   ...
}
```

In my experience this is actually surprisingly efficient - Javascript is rather good at looking up properties of objects, and it avoids a linear array scan so for larger arrays it's `O(log n)` instead of `O(n)`.

Don't use if you've messed with `Object.prototype`, though!

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of balance, the equivalent non-jQuery way (because jQuery doesn't automatically mean better):

```
if(["UNITED STATES", "USA", "AMERICA"].indexOf($('input:first').val().toUpperCase()) > -1) {
    $("#check").text("Correct!").show().fadeOut(5000);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if($.inArray($("input:first").val().toUpperCase(), ["UNITED STATES","USA","AMERICA"]) > -1){
            $("#check").text("Correct!").show().fadeOut(5000);
            return true;
}
```